# Download all blobs files locally from azure container using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using python 3.6 in visual studio and I want to download all blobs files from my azure container in single folder. This is my code but the problem is, that it downloads 1 blob file in the folder and then when downloading the second file it overwrite the first file and in the end I only have the last blob in my local folder. How can I download all the blobs files at once in a single folder?

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)

generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)
        for blob in generator:
            block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME, blob.name, LOCAL_FILE)
```

Comment: Do you mean to download them and append the blobs into a single file?

Comment: You'd need to combine them yourself. Or maybe download them to a single stream. But the `get_blob_to_path()` method isn't going to append to files.

Comment: Have you tried to pass `open_mode='ab'` to `get_blob_to_path`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think there are two solutions for your needs.

1. Download all blobs from a container, and write these blob content to a single file via the method `get_blob_to_bytes` or `get_blob_to_stream`, please see my sample code as below.

   ```
   from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

   block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)

   generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)

   fp = open('<your-local-file-name>', 'ab')

   for blob in generator:
       # Using `get_blob_to_bytes`
       b = service.get_blob_to_bytes(container_name, blob.name)
       fp.write(b.content)
       # Or using `get_blob_to_stream`
       # service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name, blob.name, fp)

   fp.flush()
   fp.close()
   ```
2. Download all blobs from a container, and write these blobs into a zip file via the method `get_blob_to_bytes`, please see my sample code below.

   ```
   from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
   import zipfile

   block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY)

   generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)

   zf = zipfile.ZipFile(CONTAINER_NAME+'.zip', 
                mode='w',
                compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, 
                )

   for blob in generator:
       b = service.get_blob_to_bytes(container_name, blob.name)
       zf.writestr(blob.name, b.content)

   zf.close()
   ```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Perfect answer..!! This is what I was looking. I think question should be edited so that google can index it.

Answer (score 1):

In the **azure-storage-blob** version `12.9.0` , I used the below script :

```py
        from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
        import zipfile
        conn_str = ''
        block_blob_service = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)
        generator = block_blob_service.get_container_client(container_name)
        my_blobs = generator.list_blobs()

        zf = zipfile.ZipFile("data"+'.zip', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for blob in my_blobs:
                bytes = generator.get_blob_client(blob.name).download_blob().readall()
                zf.writestr(blob.name, bytes)

        zf.close()
```