# How to copy the files from Azure blob to some of the path in Linux

Tags: python, linux, azure, blob, azcopy

I am trying to copy the files available in Azure blob to Linux server landing path. I am trying to use `azcopy` command, but I am unable to copy the files. Please, anyone can you help me, we are fighting for this issue from last 3 days.

Please help us.

i am trying to run the below command in Linux server and i referred microsoft web pages as well but no luck

azcopy --source XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/Container?sssssssxxxsddsxx==== --destination /JsonFiles/

--destination: command not found...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875787/download-all-blobs-files-locally-from-azure-container-using-python).

Comment: Thanks Charles. But i am unable to use the code , as i am trying to achive this in Linux server. Currenlty i have Python 3.6.3 version in our Linux server. Please help me if you have any code or by using "azcopy" command.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact command you’re using. Also include any error messages that you’re getting.

Comment: Hi gaurav , i am trying to run the below command in Linux server and i referred microsoft web pages as well but no luck 

command :   "   azcopy --source XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/Container?sssssssxxxsddsxx==== --destination /JsonFiles/      "

--destination: command not found...

Comment: Please some one can help me..

Comment: Have you seen AzCopy instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux#file-download?

Comment: Yes Gaurav, I have tried all the options but didnt worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the latest version of Azcopy and the version is v10. See the details in [Latest production version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#latest-production-version-v10). Then the steps below:

```
wget -O azcopy.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopylinux64
tar -xf azcopy.tar.gz
```

Then there is an executable file azcopy. You can get the help by running `./azcopy`. And you can use the command here to download the blob file:

```
./azcopy copy "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]" "/path/to/file.txt"
```

**Update**

In version 7.2, the command should be like this:

```
sudo azcopy --source https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob] --destination /path/to/file --source-sas "?source-sas-with-read-permission"
```

The command needs the root permission and the value of the parameter `--source-sas` is "?sas-token". Take care that there is a question mark before the SAS key inside the quotation mark.

Without Sudo it also worked, just need to add quotes. Below is the command

```
azcopy --source "https://XXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/Container?xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --destination /landing/
```

Comment: Thanks charles.. But i have version "  azcopy 7.2.0-netcore " and i am trying to use the commands mentioned in the below microsoft page which were not at all working 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux#file-download

Can you help me with the suggestion in my current existing version how can i achieve.

Comment: @avinash Do you try the command `azcopy --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/abc.txt --destination /mnt/myfiles/abc.txt --source-key sas-token`?

Comment: Yes Charles , i have tried this command and below is the output i am getting but file is not getting copied

azcopy --source https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/*.json --destination /landing/ --source-key ?xxxxxxxxxsvxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


[73] 111111
[74] 111112
[75] 111113
[74]   Done                    sv=2019-01-01
[75]   Done                    sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: its like i am getting Done Done but file is not getting copied

Comment: @avinash I use the OS Ubuntu 18.04 and there are errors to install the azcopy v7.3. The latest version is recommended, so why do you still want to use the old version? Some reasons?

Comment: as per business ( client  ) is not intrested to update the version ,because of that we are trying to find any solution if we can fix the issue

Comment: @avinash Do you try the command `azcopy --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/abc.txt
    --destination /path/to/abc.txt --source-sas "source-sas-with-read-permission"`?

Comment: Yes i tried this. But still after running the command i am gettting only one output   "  [91] Done   sv=2019-01-01  [92] Done sig = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx "

Comment: @avinash I find the issue. You can use the commmand `sudo azcopy --source https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/abc.txt --destination /path/to/abc.txt --source-sas "?source-sas-with-read-permission"`. Root permission and a `?` before the sas token.

Comment: It means i need to add Sudo at the starting of the command and what is this mean "?source-sas-with-read-permission" ( as per my understanding it should be the SAS key am  i right .

Comment: @avinash Yes, it is the SAS key. So the value of the parameter `--source-sas` is "?sas-key".

Comment: @avinash If you are the root user? So you do not need the sudo command?