# How to download a list of files from Azure Blob Storage given SAS URI and container name using Python?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I have the container name and its folder structure. I need to download all files in a single folder in the container using **python code**. I also have a SAS URL link to this particular folder.

The [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875787/download-all-blobs-files-locally-from-azure-container-using-python) I have found online use `BlockBlobService` class, which is part of the old SDK. I need to find a way to do it using the current SDK.

Can you please help me with this?

Edit 1:

this is my SAS URL: `https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER>/<FOLDER>?sp=r&st=2022-05-31T17:49:47Z&se=2022-06-05T21:59:59Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=9M8ql9nYOhEYdmAOKUyetWbCU8hoWS72UFczkShdbeY%3D`

Edit 2:

added link to the method found.

Edit 3:

I also have the full path of the files that I want to download.

Comment: What does your SAS URL look like?

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Please check the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code (untested though).

The code below basically parses the SAS URL and creates an instance of [`ContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python). Then it lists the blobs in that container names of which start with the folder name. Once you have that list, you can download individual blobs.

I noticed that your SAS URL only has `read` permission (`sp=r`). Please note that you would need both `read` and `list` permissions (`sp=rl`). You will need to ask for new SAS URL with these two permissions.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

sasUrl = "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER>/<FOLDER>?sp=r&st=2022-05-31T17:49:47Z&se=2022-06-05T21:59:59Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=9M8ql9nYOhEYdmAOKUyetWbCU8hoWS72UFczkShdbeY%3D"

sasUrlParts = urlparse(sasUrl)

accountEndpoint = sasUrlParts.scheme + '://' + sasUrlParts.netloc

sasToken = sasUrlParts.query

pathParts = sasUrlParts.path.split('/')

containerName = pathParts[1]

folderName = pathParts[2]

containerClient = ContainerClient(accountEndpoint, containerName, sasToken)

blobs = containerClient.list_blobs(folderName)

for blob in blobs_list:
  blobClient = containerClient.get_blob_client(blob)
  download the blob here...blobClient.download()
```

**UPDATE**

> I have the SAS URL mentioned above, and the full paths of the files I
> want to download. For example: PATH 1 : Container/folder/file1.csv,
> PATH 2 : Container/folder/file2.txt, and so on

Please see the code below:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

sasUrl = "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER>/<FOLDER>?sp=r&st=2022-05-31T17:49:47Z&se=2022-06-05T21:59:59Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=9M8ql9nYOhEYdmAOKUyetWbCU8hoWS72UFczkShdbeY%3D"

blobNameWithContainer = "Container/folder/file1.csv"

sasUrlParts = urlparse(sasUrl)

accountEndpoint = sasUrlParts.scheme + '://' + sasUrlParts.netloc

sasToken = sasUrlParts.query

blobSasUrl = accountEndpoint + '/' + blobNameWithContainer + '?' + sasToken;

blobClient = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blobSasUrl);
.... now do any operation on that blob ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I cannot obtain the list permission. How can I download the whole <FOLDER> (as a zip file maybe)? Pardon me if the question seems naive, this is my first time to deal with Azure.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. Folders in Azure Blob Storage are virtual. To download blobs from a virtual folder, you would first need to list the blobs in that folder and for that you would need list permission in your SAS Token. With read permission, you can only download a blob.

Comment: @Guarav I should have probably mentioned that I have the full path of each file I want to download. Can you please tell me how this can help?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have?

Comment: I have the SAS URL mentioned above, and the full paths of the files I want to download. For example:
PATH 1 : Container/folder/file1.csv,
PATH 2 : Container/folder/file2.txt,
and so on ..

Comment: Updated my answer with sample code(again untested code though). HTH.